# css - body to fill entire page even when zoomed

Tags: css, zooming

Is it possible using css to make `<html>` and/or `<body>` element to fill 100% width of browser viewport, regardless of how much it is zoomed in?

Currently, I set the html and body to 100% - but after a certain amount of zooming in, it stops and i get an ugly cut off of my header etc.

If i set it to say 5000px it works but obviously this affects non zoom too.

Therefore zoom seems to override the 100% width as it stops at a certain point and i want to overcome this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net <-- examples please!

Comment: Some browsers simply have a poorly implemented zoom feature. Not much that can be done about that.

Answer (score 0):

without an example of your code is difficult to say, but make sure that you do not have any elements with fixed width, padding, margin, borders - e.g. a div with `width: 500px;` will definitely add scrolling to your browser and push the ancestor tags out of the browser viewport boundary.